# Rally Eclipse plugin doesn't work with SSO

Tags: rally

The Rally Eclipse plugin doesn't work if you login to the Rally website via Single Sign On.
Is there a fix for this? If not where can I raise a bug?

Also, is this going to be fixed or is there any other desktop Rally tool that works with SSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just recently started on the work to upgrade the Eclipse connector to support Rally's SSO. So, you should have this in a pending future release.

~Larry Maccherone

Rally Product Owner for the Analytics and Connectors teams

Comment: Any guesstimate of the release date?

Comment: It's over a year later and the plugin still doesn't seem to work with Rally's SSO. Kinda disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a known limitation of the plugin - it does not have the hooks to use SAML-based authentication that can work with SSO. Right now the workaround is to ask your organization's Rally Subscription Administrator to "whitelist" your login from SSO such that you can authenticate using Rally-only credentials again.

You may wish to consider posting this as an Idea on [Rally Ideas](http://ideas.rallydev.com) in order to gain some traction for getting connectors/plugins for Rally the ability to authenticate using SSO.